# block_type_is_valid error on recursive function call

Tags: c++, recursion, shared-ptr

I have a module that represents a decision tree. I have two classes: Choice (which inherits from an outside class Event) and Option. A Choice represents a node of the decision tree, and an Option represents a branch. A Choice must have at least one Option. An Option can have a Choice or not. If an Option doesn't have a Choice, it is a terminal Option.

If for instance, if the decision tree looked like this:

```
A----B  
 |  
 ----C----D  
     |  
     -----E
```

Then:
A would be a Choice which has two Options (B and C).
B would be an Option without a Choice (i.e. a terminal Option).
C would be an Option with a Choice. C's Choice would contain Options D and E.

I've written my code to allow the decision tree to be as deep as needed, which is why Options have Choices and Choices have Options.

I have a function function find_terminal_options_in(EventPtr ch) with a recursive call that finds all terminal Options and gets their names. In this example, find_terminal_options_in(ptr_to_A) should return {"B","D","E"}. Instead, it fails at the end of the second call, when it is processing Option C's choice. It fails by giving the following error:

> Debug Assertion Failed!
>   Expression: _BLOCK_TYPE_IS_VALID(pHead->nBlockUse)

which is called in the shared_ptr destructor.

Is this error occurring due to a flaw in my design or a flaw in the way I'm using the shared_ptr? Any suggestions on how to get rid of this run-time error?

See my (simplified) code, which reproduces the issue:

```
class Event {
public:
    Event(std::string name):name_(name) {};
    std::string name() {return name_;};
    virtual bool is_terminal() = 0;
protected:
    std::string name_;
};

class Option;

class Choice: public Event {
public:
    Choice(): Event("") {};
    Choice(std::string name, std::list<Option> options): Event(name) {options_ = options;};
    std::list<Option> options() {return options_;};
    std::string name() {return name_;};
    bool is_terminal() {return false;};
private:
    std::list<Option> options_;
};

class Option
{
public:
    Option(std::string name, Choice choice):name_(name),choice_(choice) {};
    Option(std::string name):name_(name) {};
    Choice choice() {return choice_;};
    std::string choice_name() {return choice_.name();};
    std::string option_name() {return name_;};
private:
    Choice choice_;
    std::string name_;
};

typedef std::shared_ptr<Event> EventPtr;
typedef std::shared_ptr<Event> ChoicePtr;

std::list<std::string> find_terminal_options_in(EventPtr ch);

int main() {
    std::list<Option> temp_opts1;
    temp_opts1.push_back(Option("D"));
    temp_opts1.push_back(Option("E"));
    Choice option_Cs_choice("option_Cs_choice",temp_opts1);

    std::list<Option> temp_opts2;
    temp_opts2.push_back(Option("C",option_Cs_choice));
    temp_opts2.push_back(Option("B"));
    EventPtr ptr_to_A = EventPtr(new Choice("A",temp_opts2));

    std::list<std::string> terminal_options = find_terminal_options_in(ptr_to_A);
}

std::list<std::string> find_terminal_options_in(EventPtr ch)
{
    std::list<std::string> returned_list;

    std::shared_ptr<Choice> choice = std::dynamic_pointer_cast<Choice>(ch);
    std::list<Option> choice_options = choice->options();

    for(std::list<Option>::iterator options_it = choice_options.begin();options_it != choice_options.end(); options_it++)
    {
        if(options_it->choice_name() != "") //it has a choice
        {
            Choice option_choice = options_it->choice();
            find_terminal_options_in(EventPtr(&option_choice));
        }
        else //it doesn't have a choice, and is therefore a terminal option
            returned_list.push_back(options_it->option_name());
    }

    return returned_list;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are 2 problems with your code:

1. For recursion to work properly, you need to change signature from

   std::list find_terminal_options_in(EventPtr ch);

to

```
void find_terminal_options_in(EventPtr ch,std::list<std::string> &output);
```

Otherwise, data obtained in

```
find_terminal_options_in(EventPtr(&option_choice));
```

is lost.

1. In line

   ```
   find_terminal_options_in(EventPtr(&option_choice));
   ```

you are creating shared pointer from non dynamically allocated object - that cannot be done, and this is the reason for the erro you are getting. You can only instantiate shared pointer from objects created using new. Quick fix would be

```
        find_terminal_options_in(EventPtr(new Choice(option_choice)));
```

Proper fix - to store shared pointer to Choice instead of Choice in Option.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is: you missed the

```
virtual ~Event() {}
```

in class Event.
As soon as you go back from the function-call stack, the instance "ch" would be deleted.

```
std::list<std::string>  find_terminal_options_in(EventPtr ch)  { ... }
```

But it does not call the Choice's Deconstructor, although it was constructed in main() with.

```
EventPtr ptr_to_A = EventPtr(new Choice("A",temp_opts2));
```

Try it with "virtual ~Event()" and the problem will disappear. :-)